# Slow query in DocumentDB

Tags: aws-documentdb

I have a DocumentDB with some really slow queries and peaks of CPU. One of the slowest queries based on the profiler, its the following. I'm trying to understand what kind of issue could cause this query to be slow freaking slow:

```
{
  "op":"update",
  "ts":1597203362481,
  "ns":"db.registrations",
  "command":{
    "q":{
      "_id":"5ca3f02edb3fb733eb2f0f46"
    },
    "u":{
      "$set":{
        "last_active_at":"2020-08-12T03:33:43.278Z",
        "updated_at":"2020-08-12T03:33:43.278Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "nMatched":1,
  "nModified":1,
  "protocol":"op_query",
  "millis":139201,
  "planSummary":"IXSCAN",
  "execStats":{
    "stage":"UPDATE",
    "nReturned":"0",
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"138855.197",
    "inputStages":[
      {
        "stage":"LIMIT_SKIP",
        "nReturned":"1",
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"138822.167",
        "inputStage":{
          "stage":"IXSCAN",
          "nReturned":"1",
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"0.305",
          "indexName":"_id_",
          "direction":"forward"
        }
      },
      {
        "stage":"IXSCAN",
        "nReturned":"1",
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"138841.412",
        "indexName":"_id_",
        "direction":"forward"
      }
    ]
  },
  "client":"10.70.13.125:42436",
  "user":"db"
}
```

Neither those fields: `last_active_at` or `updated_at` have index. So why this could being so slow?

Comment: how many docs are you updating?

Comment: how large are your updates and what is your instance size? By default Amazon DocumentDB has an index on _id_, and on every insert the query optimizer uses the index to find the documents to update.